# Sqlalchemy dynamic where statements

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

From sqlalchemy documentation we have the following example:

```
s = (
select((users.c.fullname + ", " + addresses.c.email_address).label("title"))
.where(users.c.id == addresses.c.user_id)
.where(users.c.name.between("m", "z"))
.where(
    or_(
        addresses.c.email_address.like("%@aol.com"),
        addresses.c.email_address.like("%@msn.com"),
    )
))
```

The thing here is that the above statement has a predefined set of `where` clauses. I would like to have a more dynamic query that will depend on the input I get from the client of columns and values I need to use. For example in plain sql :

```
Select * from users where column1 =  value1

Select * from users where column1 =  value1 and column2 = value2 and column3 = value3
```

So the two queries above can be formed depending on the input I get from the client. The input will be as dict like.

```
d_1 = {column1 : value1}
d_2 = {column1: value1, column2 : value2, column3: value3}
```

So depending on the dictionary I want to increase or decrease the amount of WHERE clauses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72491726/2144390

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to store filter data in different format?

```
filters_1 = [
    users.c.id == addresses.c.user_id,
    users.c.name.between("m", "z")
]
```

If yes, you can implement your idea like below (I have not run this code, and it may contain errors):

```
T = TypeVar("T")

def apply_filters(st: Select[T], filters: list) -> Select[T]:
    for flt in filters:
        st = st.where(flt)
    return st

filters_1 = [
    users.c.id == addresses.c.user_id,
    users.c.name.between("m", "z")
]

filters_2 = [
    users.c.id == addresses.c.user_id,
    or_(
        addresses.c.email_address.like("%@aol.com"),
        addresses.c.email_address.like("%@msn.com"),
    )
]

st_1 = apply_filters(select(User), filters_1)

st_2 = apply_filters(select(User), filters_2)
```